# Changing dates of particuler item in listView

Tags: android, sqlite, date, listview

I have a button reschedule in my app, pressing it'll automatically change the past dates of the To-dos with the current date, but the problem is that with the following code, it also changes the future dates with the current one, i dont have any code under else-if but it still changes the future date with current.

```
public void updateDates2() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID,
                    TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
            },
            null, null, null, null, null);

    String formattedDate = formatter.format(c.getTime());

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //Getting dates into the array using Cursor.
        String datesfromdb = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
        array.add(datesfromdb);
    }
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String TEMPPCOLNAME = "checkdate";
    Cursor csr = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{
                    // All existing columns
                    "*",
                    "rowid as uid",
                    // generate reformatted date column named checkdate usable by date functions
                    // i.e. converts dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-yy
                    "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",7,4)||'-'||" +
                            "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",4,2)||'-'||" +
                            "substr( " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",1,2) AS " + TEMPPCOLNAME},
            // where clause to only include properly formatted dates and those who date is less
            // than or equaly to today's date
            TEMPPCOLNAME + "<= date('now') AND " +
                    "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",3,1) = '/' AND " +
                    "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",6,1) = '/'",
            null, null, null, null
    );


    Toast.makeText(this, csr.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            if (array.get(i).equals(formattedDate)) {
                //If comparision matches, then incrementing the current date by one.
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                formattedDate = formatter.format(c.getTime());
            } else {
                //if the date doesn't matches then returning the date to the db.update to set this date to the current task.
                cv.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE, formattedDate);
            }
        }

        if (

                db.update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, cv, "rowid=?", new String[]{
                        String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("uid")))}
                ) > 0) {
            Log.d("UPDT2", "Row Updated OK.");
        } else {
            Log.d("UPDT2", "Update failed.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you debug code for checking update the date in database  or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue, as you describe, is with this line :-

```
db.update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, cv, String.valueOf(idx1), null);
```

and specifically the 3rd (WHERE clause) parameter i.e. `String.valueOf(idx1)`

You are effectively saying WHERE n (*n being the offset/index of the column `TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE`*). If this column index is greater than 0 then the expression will effectively be true and thus every row will be updated.

So this update only has to be executed once and it, if the column index is greater then 0 (true), will update all rows.Which appears to be the behavior that you have described.

You need the parameter to be something like `TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE = 'CurrentDate'`.

Or preferably `TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE=?` with the 4th parameter resolving the **?** placeholder e.g. `newString[]{dateDB}`.

This would update all rows with that date, which may result in the needles update attempts. For example if you had two past dates that were the same, both would be updated when the cursor reaches that row and when the cursor reaches the other row.

I'd suggest only extracting the rows to be updated, this isn't made easy as you appear to have the date stored as dd/mm/yyyy (which is not easily sorted according to date sequence). However, you can get around that by creating a column in the extracted cursor that re-formats the date and allows it to be checked.

This does look a little complex here's an example :-

```
String TEMPPCOLNAME = "checkdate";
        Cursor csr = db.query(TBNAME,new String[]{
                // All existing columns
                "*",
                "rowid as uid",
                // generate reformatted date column named checkdate usable by date functions
                // i.e. converts dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-yy
                "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",7,4)||'-'||" +
                        "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",4,2)||'-'||" +
                        "substr( " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",1,2) AS " + TEMPPCOLNAME },
                // where clause to only include properly formatted dates and those who date is less
                // than or equaly to today's date
                TEMPPCOLNAME + "<= date('now') AND " +
                        "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",3,1) = '/' AND " +
                        "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",6,1) = '/'",
                null,null,null,null
                );
```

This is saying get a Cursor with all columns in the table (*), make the Cursor have a column called **uid** which is an alias of the **rowid** and also make the Cursor have a column called **checkdate** (name as per TEMPCOLNAME). checkdate being the reformatted date (now yyyy-mm-dd as SQLite likes)

The WHERE clause (third paramter) is what is used to only select dates that are less than or equal to whatever is defined in the 4th parameter that will replace the **?** placeholder.

The WHERE parameter also restricts the selected rows to those whose date has **/** at positions  3 and 6 (just a precaution).

The update is then quite straightforward and importantly specific to a single row (hence why the column **uid** was extracted) :-

```
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        db.update(TBNAME,cv,"rowid=?",new String[]{
                String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("uid")))}
                ); 
    }
    csr.close();
```

Combining both, you could have:-

```
public void updateDates2() {
    String TEMPPCOLNAME = "checkdate";
    Cursor csr = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,new String[]{
            // All existing columns
            "*",
            "rowid as uid",
            // generate reformatted date column named checkdate usable by date functions
            // i.e. converts dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-yy
            "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",7,4)||'-'||" +
                    "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",4,2)||'-'||" +
                    "substr( " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",1,2) AS " + TEMPPCOLNAME },
            // where clause to only include properly formatted dates and those who date is less
            // than or equaly to today's date
            TEMPPCOLNAME + "<= date('now') AND " +
                    "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",3,1) = '/' AND " +
                    "substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",6,1) = '/'",
            null,null,null,null
            );
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        if (
        db.update(TBNAME,cv,"rowid=?",new String[]{
                String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("uid")))}
                ) > 0) {
            Log.d("UPDT2","Row Updated OK.");
        } else {
            Log.d("UPDT2", "Update failed.");
        }
    }
    csr.close();
}
```

#### using the above testing provided the following results :-

```
10-27 09:32:51.482 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 1 - Event Name is Event1 Starts on 01/03/2011 Ends on 2021-03-21
10-27 09:32:51.482 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 2 - Event Name is Event2 Starts on 14/08/2014 Ends on 2020-03-21
10-27 09:32:51.482 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 3 - Event Name is Event3 Starts on 26/10/2017 Ends on 2017-12-21
10-27 09:32:51.482 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 4 - Event Name is Event4 Starts on 28/10/2017 Ends on 2018-21-31
10-27 09:32:51.482 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 5 - Event Name is Event5 Starts on 01/01/2018 Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 09:32:51.482 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 6 - Event Name is Event6 Starts on 27/10/2018 Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 09:32:51.482 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 7 - Event Name is Event7 Starts on garbage Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 09:32:51.483 4259-4259/? D/UPDT2: Extracted Row for Event Event1 StartDate Stored = 01/03/2011 Converted to = 2011-03-01
10-27 09:32:51.487 4259-4259/? D/UPDT2: Row Updated OK.
10-27 09:32:51.487 4259-4259/? D/UPDT2: Extracted Row for Event Event2 StartDate Stored = 14/08/2014 Converted to = 2014-08-14
10-27 09:32:51.491 4259-4259/? D/UPDT2: Row Updated OK.
10-27 09:32:51.491 4259-4259/? D/UPDT2: Extracted Row for Event Event3 StartDate Stored = 26/10/2017 Converted to = 2017-10-26
10-27 09:32:51.495 4259-4259/? D/UPDT2: Row Updated OK.
10-27 09:32:51.495 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 1 - Event Name is Event1 Starts on 27/10/2017 Ends on 2021-03-21
10-27 09:32:51.495 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 2 - Event Name is Event2 Starts on 27/10/2017 Ends on 2020-03-21
10-27 09:32:51.495 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 3 - Event Name is Event3 Starts on 27/10/2017 Ends on 2017-12-21
10-27 09:32:51.495 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 4 - Event Name is Event4 Starts on 28/10/2017 Ends on 2018-21-31
10-27 09:32:51.495 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 5 - Event Name is Event5 Starts on 01/01/2018 Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 09:32:51.495 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 6 - Event Name is Event6 Starts on 27/10/2018 Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 09:32:51.495 4259-4259/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 7 - Event Name is Event7 Starts on garbage Ends on 2018-12-31
```

The first 7 lines are the data prior to the above being run, the last 7 after. The 6 lines between are form the update itself *(I removed the code to produce the Extracted Row ....., the Converted to is the value of checkdate i.e. the reformatted date)*

#### However, perhaps the best method would be to have a single update that can do away with the need for a cursor to extract the rows:-

```
public void updateDates() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String formattedDate = formatter.format(c.getTime());

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE,formattedDate);

    String whereclause =
            " substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE +  ",7,4)||" +
                    " substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",4,2)||" +
                    " substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",1,2) " +
                    " <= date('now') " +
                    " AND substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",3,1) = '/'" +
                    " AND substr(" + TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_DATE + ",6,1) = '/'";
    db.update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,cv,whereclause,null);
}
```

Testing Data :-

```
10-27 11:25:52.331 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 1 - Event Name is Event1 Starts on 01/03/2011 Ends on 2021-03-21
10-27 11:25:52.331 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 2 - Event Name is Event2 Starts on 14/08/2014 Ends on 2020-03-21
10-27 11:25:52.331 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 3 - Event Name is Event3 Starts on 26/10/2017 Ends on 2017-12-21
10-27 11:25:52.331 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 4 - Event Name is Event4 Starts on 28/10/2017 Ends on 2018-21-31
10-27 11:25:52.331 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 5 - Event Name is Event5 Starts on 01/01/2018 Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 11:25:52.331 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 6 - Event Name is Event6 Starts on 27/10/2018 Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 11:25:52.332 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 7 - Event Name is Event7 Starts on garbage Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 11:25:52.335 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 1 - Event Name is Event1 Starts on 27/10/2017 Ends on 2021-03-21
10-27 11:25:52.335 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 2 - Event Name is Event2 Starts on 27/10/2017 Ends on 2020-03-21
10-27 11:25:52.335 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 3 - Event Name is Event3 Starts on 26/10/2017 Ends on 2017-12-21
10-27 11:25:52.335 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 4 - Event Name is Event4 Starts on 28/10/2017 Ends on 2018-21-31
10-27 11:25:52.335 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 5 - Event Name is Event5 Starts on 01/01/2018 Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 11:25:52.335 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 6 - Event Name is Event6 Starts on 27/10/2018 Ends on 2018-12-31
10-27 11:25:52.335 5250-5250/? D/EVENTDATA: Row 7 - Event Name is Event7 Starts on garbage Ends on 2018-12-31
```

Comment: db.update(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, cv,"strftime('%d/%m/%Y', DATE) <=?",strftime('%d/%m%Y',CurrentDate)); Android studio is just not accepting this line, getting error at <=?(expressions expected) And second strftime (can't resolve strftime)

Comment: Edited answer (again untested) 4th parameter needs to be a String array of the placeholder replacements.

Comment: @Birdielove sorry, after testing the previous could was no good. I've now edited the code with code that works as the testing shows.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a life saver for me, really can't express my happiness and thanks in words. People like you make the StackOverflow a better place.

Comment: i added some more functionality into the updateDate2 method, what i wanted to do is that change the past dates to the current but if there's already an entry for current date, then it should increment the current date and set it.